# how to find duplicate file name using file:find?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to write a program to find duplicate file names in multiple drive using perl. This is my script, but it gives wrong info.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Find;
@filename;
@path;
$count;
open my $out, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;
my $file = "E:";
find( \&edit, "$file" );

sub edit() {
    $count++;
    push( @filename, $_ );
    push( @path,     $File::Find::name );
}
print "Processing.";
for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++ ) {
    for ( my $j = $i + 1 ; $j < $count ; $j++ ) {
        if ( $filename[$i] =~ /\Q$filename[$j]\E/ ) {
            print $out("$filename[$i] = $filename[$j]\n");
            print ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but example i am mention only one.

Answer (score 3):

You should always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  However, you lucked and that didn't lead to any errors.

In fact, other than using a regex to test when you should've used [`eq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eq.html), your script looks functional.  As a style change though, I would've saved all paths in a hash of arrays to more easily find matching files.  Especially as currently your method wouldn't list groups of 3 or more together.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find;

my %files;

open my $out, '>', 'output.txt';
my $file = "E:";

find( \&edit, "$file" );

sub edit() {
    push @{$files{$_}}, $File::Find::name;
}

while (my ($file, $paths) = each %files) {
    next if @$paths == 1;
    print "$file @$paths\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain push and while that you used in  the program and paths also.

Comment: It's possible to find only pdf or mp3 in a drive ?

Answer (score 0):

Kathir, the module File::Find::Rule is pretty powerful and easy to use. To find only mp3 files do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $directory_to_look_in = '/tmp/you/know';
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.mp3')->in($directory_to_look_in);
```

Comment: will this only search for mp3 file alone,i have tried for type log extension,nothing is turned up

Comment: @Venaktesan It works for every extension. Maybe your filesystem make a difference between .LOG and .log; you can leave out ->name(...) to find every file and look at the results

Comment: @files contains only file directory, by using this we cant compare file directory to find duplicate file. In file::find there is "_$" to get only file name what about in file:find:rule