# Find all instances of every file name in a directory tree

Tags: perl, unix, find

This Perl script has a search function that searches for files in subdirectories that have the same filename.

The output generated must be something like this:

```
file_name1: ~/X/file_name1 ~/?/??/file_name1
file_name2: ~/X/XYZ/file_name2 ~/?/?????/ ??/file_name2
```

I have tried the way using below:

```
find . -type f | perl -e'

while ( <> ) { 
    chomp; 
    push @{ $h{ substr($_, rindex($_, "/") + 1) } }, $_;
}

for $k (keys %h) { 
    next if @{ $h{$k} } < 2; 
    print "$k: @{ $h{$k} }\n"
}'
```

Does anyone have another solution to this?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Any other efficient solution will be helpful@melpomene

Comment: Are you just asking for a code review?

Comment: Perl has a `Find` module, so you could easily eliminate the dependency on a separate process for the command line `find`.  Whether that's more "efficient" or not, I can't say.  This is an OS/file system-bound task. Speed will be dependent on details that have nothing to do with your program.

Comment: I strongly suggest not to "request" things in your posts, specially not in a title. You _are_ posting a question, so that's that.  (If you don't like my change go to "edit" link and edit or roll back to a previous version.).  Also, I suggest that you state what is wrong with the code you post, instead of your last line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because I don't understand what your question is. You appear to have written something that works; surely you don't want a collection of many ways to do the same thing?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for duplicate files, simply put.

A couple of approaches

- There is a module [File::Find::Duplicates](http://search.cpan.org/~tmtm/File-Find-Duplicates-1.00/lib/File/Find/Duplicates.pm), what may just solve your problem directly.
- Use a module to find all files, say [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm). Then use one of many ways to find duplicates in list(s), or use a hash (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23862719/4653379)). Use MD5 to confirm that the *files* are the same.

There are posts on SO on details mentioned above, and in fact on the whole topic, please search.